# ¿Como puedo saber cual es la palabra mas corta ingresada dentro de un arreglo?

Tags: java

Necesito saber dentro de esto código , la palabra mas corta ingresada por el usuario al arreglo

Ej : Si pongo que mi arreglo será de largo 3
Ingreso mi primera palabra: Hola
Ingreso mi segunda palabra: mundo
ingreso mi tercera palabra: nuevamente

Como saber mediante una función o algo por el estilo , que la palabra mas corta ingresada dentro del arreglo es "Hola". De ante mano muchas gracias.

```
    int N=0;
    int condicion=1;
    while(condicion!=0) {
        
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese el largo del arreglo");
    N=rd.nextInt();
    
    
    if(N<=0) {
        System.out.println("N TIENE QUE SER MAYOR A 0");
        
    }else {
        condicion=0; //sale del ciclo repetitivo
    }

    }
    
    rd.nextLine();
    
    
    String[] palabras=new String[N];
    int [] largopalabra =new int[N];
    
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
        System.out.println("Por favor ingresar palabra numero: "+(i+1));
        palabras[i]=rd.nextLine();
        largopalabra[i]=palabras[i].length();
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
        System.out.println(palabras[i]+"-----------------"+largopalabra[i]);
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Inténtalo, es muy sencillo. Tienes que recorrer el array de `String` uno a uno comprobando su longitud (con la función `length()` de la clase `String`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compañero, una opción sería implementar la función **devolverPalabraMasCorta()** la cual recibe un array, que te muestro más abajo. En ella, en la variable **palabraMasCorta** cojo una palabra de dicho array (por ejemplo, la primera) y la voy **comparando**, recorriendo el array dentro del bucle for de la función, con el resto de palabras. Si hay alguna más pequeña, asigno su valor a la variable **palabraMasCorta**.

**Código**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner rd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N=0;
        int condicion=1;
        while(condicion!=0) {


        System.out.println("Ingrese el largo del arreglo");
        N=rd.nextInt();


        if(N<=0) {
            System.out.println("N TIENE QUE SER MAYOR A 0");

        }else {
            condicion=0; //sale del ciclo repetitivo
        }

        }

        rd.nextLine();


        String[] palabras=new String[N];
        int [] largopalabra =new int[N];

        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
            System.out.println("Por favor ingresar palabra numero: "+(i+1));
            palabras[i]=rd.nextLine();
            largopalabra[i]=palabras[i].length();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
            System.out.println(palabras[i]+"-----------------"+largopalabra[i]);
        }
        
        devolverPalabraMasCorta(palabras);
    
    }

    public static void devolverPalabraMasCorta(String array[]){
        String palabraMasCorta = array[0];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].length() < palabraMasCorta.length()){
                palabraMasCorta = array[i];
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("La palabra más corta es " + "\"" + palabraMasCorta + "\""); 
    }
}
```

**Salida**:

```
Ingrese el largo del arreglo
3
Por favor ingresar palabra numero: 1
Hola
Por favor ingresar palabra numero: 2
Stack
Por favor ingresar palabra numero: 3
Overflow
Hola-----------------4
Stack-----------------5
Overflow-----------------8
La palabra más corta es "Hola"
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Hermano, una idea que te doy es coger el arreglo despues de agregarle todas las palabras y usar un metodo que tienen las listas  llamado sort. Usas algo como

```
Arrays.sort(palabras);
```

y ya solo te queda obtener el primer valor un ejemplo te lo dejo abajo

```
Arrays.sort(palabras);
String palabraMasCorta = palabras[0];
```

y por lo contrario la palabra mas larga seria el tamanio de tu arreglo - 1

```
String palabraMasLarga = palabras(palabras.length - 1);
```